# DLLImport c++ function with default parameters

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, default-parameters

I am trying to import a function from an unmanaged code c++ dll into my c# application.  The c++ prototype is

```
int somefunction (int param1, int *param2 = NULL);
```

How do I declare this in c# to take advantage of the default nature of param2?  The following code does not work.  param2 gets initialized with garbage.

```
DllImportAttribute("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "somefunction")]
public static extern int somefunction(int param1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C# 4.0 then dtb`s answer is the right approach.  C# 4.0 added optional parameter support and they work just as well with PInvoke functions.

Prior to C# 4.0 there is no way to take advantage of the optional parameter.  The closest equivalent is to define one function that forwards into the other.

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "somefunction")] 
static extern int somefunction(int param1, IntPtr param2);

static int somefunction(int param1) {
  someFunction(param1, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "somefunction")]
static unsafe extern int somefunction(int param1, int* param2 = null);
```

or

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "somefunction")]
static extern int somefunction(int param1, IntPtr param2 = default(IntPtr));
```

Comment: Thanks but neither of those options will compile.

Comment: They compile fine here, but I can't test if they actually work, because I don't have your unmanaged dll.